# jquery: calling a function from variable with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call back a function which is defined in a variable(I did this)...
More than this how to pass variable into that function(which is also defined as variable)

Example: 
Functionvariable,variable are variables....

```
function ffunction(Functionvariable,variable){
     Functionvariable(variable); //This is actually not working...how to do this...
}
```

I tried this,

```
function ffunction(Functionvariable,variable){
     eval(Functionvariable + '('+ variable + ')'); //no luck
}
```

This is worked...

```
function ffunction(Functionvariable,variable){
         eval(Functionvariable)(variable);
    }
```

Comment: how is this method called

Comment: I hope that your arg is not called Function because Function has a special meaning in javascript

Comment: Your first example is correct, if you're trying to do what it looks like. `ffunction(alert, 3)` will alert `3`.

Comment: do you have any errors in console?

Comment: take this for example: `var g = function(){alert("called")};function f2(fn,v){fn(v)};f2(g,1)` This is the same example as yours but it works

Comment: @Emil... note both are variables.. so i can't call it what you mention...

Comment: in my example fn arg is also a variable

Comment: what you mean that is a variable? you mean that is a string ? like `var myfunc = "somefunc"` ?

Comment: some function name I am passing through that variable.... that function is doing lot of other works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just avoid reserved words and you shall be fine with your first solution.
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6R3ye/

```
function dummy(func, v){
    eval(func)(v);
};
var f = 'alert';
var x = 'abc';
dummy(f, x);
```

Comment: I mentioned.. func here is also variables... I am passing some name as variable....

Comment: Now it's what you want

Comment: @AnishCharles it was a bit hard to understand what you mean, because variable can also hold function instance. Please accept the answer and possibly upvote. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I gathered 4 methods you can use, with 1 or more params

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8y5q/16/)

```
function ffunction(fn, p1, p2) {
  console.log("ffunction is calling \n" + fn.toString() + "\nwith " + p1.toString());

  eval(fn)(p1, p2);
  fn(p1, p2);
  fn.call(fn, p1, p2);
  fn.apply(fn, [p1, p2]);
}

function f1(p1, p2){
  console.log("f1 got " + p1.toString() + " and " + p2.toString());
}

ffunction(f1, 'foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: You haven't read the comments. Only your first solution will work if `fn` holds the name of the function as a string. The problem is already solved. @Anish please accept the working answer.